# Passing the lat, lng information to the google map script

Tags: geoip

I've have an index.html file that includes a gogglemap.js file to display a map of users location. Currently I am attempting to add the proper code to the index.html to pass the lat, lng info to the js file.

Here is filler content for the index file to show what I am attempting to do:

```html
<h3><display user city></h3>  <---- this needs to display users city and has filler text to show what I am trying to accomplish.

<div id="map"></div>

<script>var lat=12.356;var lng=-19.31;var country="User Country";var city="User City";</script> <----- seems like it is getting the lat/lng somehow before the index page loads and inserting this script into the index file?
```

Here is the js file code:

```js
var styles = [{yourcustomstyle}]

var myLatlng = { lat: lat, lng: lng };

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    styles: styles,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions );

  for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {

    c = Math.random();
    c = c * (0 == 1E6 * c % 2 ? 1 : -1);
    d = Math.random() 
    d = d * (0 == 1E6 * d % 2 ? 1 : -1);
    c = new google.maps.LatLng( lat + 0.08 * c + 0.052, lng + 0.2 * d + 0.08),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: c,
      icon: 'marker.png'
    });

  }

}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild( script );
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: In what order are you including your js file? So before or after your variables are declared in the HTML?

Comment: It is located before the closing body tag, so after. Seems like I'm missing a script that fills in the lat/lng. Then calls the js file.<script>var lat=12.356;var lng=-19.31;var country="User Country";var city="User City";</script> <script src="googlemap.js"></script> I actually tried putting it before, in the header area.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint to your initialize code, what are the values of lat and lng?

Comment: The values you see for lat/lng are hard coded from me downloading the html page, which should be php. So those values are being generated by my geo location and do not reflect the actual code that it should be. Is there a way to PM the rest of the code?

Comment: No you will have to post it all here

Comment: ok, I will post my question in a private forum. Thank you for attempting to help.